# Converter data MySQL dd/mm/yyyy para yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, data

Tenho um banco de dados onde eu inseria as datas no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` (exemplo: `05/11/1987`), mas agora estou organizando uns relatórios e preciso atualizar todas as datas no banco de dados para o formato `yyyy-mm-dd` (`1987-11-05`). Como faço isso no MySQL?

Lembrando que esta não é uma duplicata, pois estou querendo atualizar os dados no banco de dados e não selecionar eles em um outro formato.

Comment: Você precisa atualizar estes dados para este novo formato ou trazer (SELECT) no formato yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Boa tarde @FelipeDouradinho, Então eu preciso atualizar estes dados para o novo formato.

Comment: Maicon, não é duplicata.

Comment: Seu campo é do tipo date? Ou varchar? O que o PHP tem a ver com essa pergunta?

Comment: @KaduAmaral a resposta do Felipe Douradinho resolveu aqui meu problema o campo e varchar mas para eu mudar ele para date tinha que fazer essa atualização das informações se não eu perderia elas

Comment: Correto @CristianoCardosoSilva, bom que já conseguiu. ;) 
Se a resposta dele lhe foi útil, não se esqueça de dar um voto a favor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Cristiano**, aqui o que você precisa:

```
UPDATE tbl_data SET data =
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE data LIKE '__/__/____'
```

**Antes**

23/11/1987

**Depois**

1987-11-23

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, Muito obrigado

Comment: Ótimo! Muito bom! Obrigado.

Comment: Não é necessário o "where", se você sabe que o mês e o dia estejam no formato de 2 dígitos. Mesmo assim, se tiver algum dado que não se conforma ao teste, vai retornar "0000-00-00".

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer uma string vira uma data apenas com as funções disponíves no mysql como [str_to_time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) e depois usar [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para trocar o formato.

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date('30/01/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Ele quer atualizar (`UPDATE`), não selecionar (`SELECT`)

Comment: Já atualizo minha resposta mas ideia é a mesma. Obrigado pela correção @FelipeDouradinho

Comment: Realmente, não havia reparado! Ficam as duas para a posteridade então, hehe

Comment: não era o que o cara queria, mas me serviu muito. obrigado.