# Intervalo de datas VARCHAR/DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, data

Possuo um campo de nome date (tipo `VARCHAR`) na minha tabela, e recentemente precisei pesquisar no banco de dados com intervalo de datas.

E para isso usei o operador `Between`, ficando algo como: `BETWEEN 15/08/2015 AND 25/08/2015`. Até ai tudo bem.

O problema é quando preciso procurar de um mes para outro, algo como: `BETWEEN 25/07/2015 AND 25/08/2015`, ai não dá certo, e acredito fielmente que isso deve-se ao problema do campo date ser do tipo `VARCHAR` e não do tipo date.

Estou disposto a mudar o formato das datas para 0000-00-00, o problema é que na hora de capturar estes dados não posso mostrar neste formato, já que aqui o padrão é 00/00/0000.

Bom, preciso para solução disso, como faço para conformar o formato 0000-00-00 em 00/00/0000, ou ainda, outra forma de pesquisar o intervalo dos registros, afim de não usar o campo date para isso.

Comment: Realmente eu converteria o tipo mas pra resolver a busca tentou `STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d-%m-%Y')`? Se for este o formato que sua data está.

Comment: Resolve parte do problema [Converter data MySQL dd/mm/yyyy para yyyy-mm-dd](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72033/91)

Comment: Se você pretende mudar o formato das datas, não é melhor mudar o tipo do campo para `DATE`, então? Isso resolveria todos os seus problemas e o banco fica consistente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma é fazer a conversão. Teria que criar uma nova coluna do tipo `DATE` e fazer um `UPDATE` para gravar nessa coluna a data pegando da coluna antiga que ainda está como `VARCHAR`. Provavelmente usando isto: `STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d-%m-%Y')`.

```
UPDATE tabela SET datanova = STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Depois você apaga a coluna velha e renomeia a nova. Claro que todas aplicações que acessas esta tabelas precisam estar preparadas para esta mudança.

Esta mesma expressão pode ser usada para converter a coluna na hora de fazer a busca, se preferir não converter. Assim pode usar a data normalmente.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d-%m-%Y')
                           BETWEEN '2015/08/15' AND '2015/08/25'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/DateInterval.sql).

Estou considerando que sua data está separada por `-`. Se não for isto, mude o separador.

Comment: bigown, tentei deste jeito mas parece não funcionar, veja que eu tenho que buscar entre as datas formatadas e não como elas estavam anteriormente, assim fica correto:  `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('15/10/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('18/10/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')`, no meu caso o separador é `/` e o campo de datas é o `date`.