# Convert date não retorna valor esperado

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Para fazer a atualização do PHP no meu sistema instalei-o em uma nova maquina com uma versão mais atualizado do PHP (7.3) e do Ubuntu (20.04). Após isso percebi que algumas querys estavam retornando um valores errados devido a data.

O problema é que nas querys o convert date está retornando um valor fora do esperado.

```
select 
   count(*) as total, 
   convert(date,c.data_importacao) as importacao_dt,
   c.cod_transportadora,
   a.docknox_status
 from 
   tb_Servicos a WITH (NOLOCK)
   join tb_clientes c1 with (NOLOCK) on a.cod_cliente=c1.cod_cliente 
   and (c1.cod_cliente='799' or c1.cod_pai = '799')
   left join tb_Status_DOCKNOX_x_Cliente b  WITH (NOLOCK) on a.docknox_status = b.cod_status
   left join tb_arquivos_importados c  WITH (NOLOCK) on a.cod_arquivo=c.cod_arquivo
   left join tb_opl d  WITH (NOLOCK) on c.cod_opl=d.cod_opl
 where
   a.ativo = '1' 
   and a.morto is null
   and convert(date,c.data_importacao)>='2021-11-01' 
   and convert(date,c.data_importacao)<='2021-11-25' 
 group by 
   convert(date,c.data_importacao),
   c.cod_transportadora,
   a.docknox_status
 order by 
   convert(date,c.data_importacao) desc,
   a.docknox_status
```

O valor retornado do campo 'importacao_dt' é

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o valor que deveria ser retornado deveria estar nesse formato

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tipo de dado da coluna é datetime2. Consegui fazer funcionar usando o convert(datetime,...), porém alterando a query dessa forma o nosso ambiente de QA não funciona.

Gostaria de saber o por que do convert estar retornando neste formato.

Comment: não funciona se usar simplesmente `c.data_importacao >= '20211101' `?

Comment: Funciona, porém ficaria inviável fazer essa alteração em todas as querys do sistema, a questão é que funciona normalmente no ambiente de QA usando o convert(date,...), porém nessa nova maquina não funciona.

Comment: nesse caso compare as configurações do servidor com o que tem o resultado e esperado e faça as alterações para que fiquem iguais

Comment: Não daria para usar o date_format no importacao_dt ? Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72033/converter-data-mysql-dd-mm-yyyy-para-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: A solução foi usar o convert para nvarchar no 'importacao_dt'.
`convert(nvarchar(100),c.data_importacao,23)` Para date
`convert(nvarchar(100),c.data_importacao,120)` Para datetime